# Dulux silk paint peeled off after removing masking tape hell

Tags: painting

[image]

That grey paint was there for a few months and it decided to peel off after I removed the masking tape which was only left on for 10-20 mins

Should I remove all the grey paint and do something like get a primer, I’m not sure how this stuff works

Comment: Masking tape will pull paint off the walls. In the future use the painter's tape (blue).

Comment: How much area are we talking about?

Comment: How did you prepare the original surface before painting the grey?

Comment: is this in a kitchen?